# How do I silently write to a temporary file?

Tags: files

I made a modification in `org-pomodoro` to send the mode line to a pipe which I use in `xmobar`, but it keeps spamming my `*Messages*` buffer, thus making the line which displays it almost useless.

```el
(write-region
 (concat "\ue003 "
         (org-pomodoro-format-seconds)
         (org-clock-get-clock-string)
         "\n")
 nil
 "/tmp/.todo-pipe")
```

I inserted the expression above in the "tick" function and everything is working as expected. Initially I made a shell script, but I think implementing the logic inside Emacs is a better solution, since I'm using `org-pomodoro`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it keeps spamming my `*Messages*` buffer

I assume you're referring to the `"Wrote FILENAME"` message that `write-region` emits. This message can be inhibited by giving it a non-boolean, non-string value as the 5th `VISIT` argument. From the docstring of `write-region`:

```
If VISIT is neither t nor nil nor a string, or if Emacs is in batch mode,
  do not display the "Wrote file" message.
```

This is also documented in the Elisp manual under [`(elisp) Writing to Files`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-to-Files.html).

So, you could write something like the following:

```el
(write-region (concat "\ue003 "
                      (org-pomodoro-format-seconds)
                      (org-clock-get-clock-string)
                      "\n")
              nil "/tmp/.todo-pipe"
              nil 'quiet)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it, I didn't noticed that when I was reading the documentation.